# Several containers with a height of 100% each below the other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create the following layout with twitter bootstrap. Several containers each below the other and every container have height equals to browser screen height. User will be able to scroll up and down through them. I'm searching is there something ready in bootstrap - .container-browser-height or something?

[image]

I made edit to share lesson learned. In twitter bootstrap there is no build in class for this purpose. I searched in the code. So the answer from Krzysztof Krawiec solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm don't think that bootstrap have premaded component for full window height.
Anyway you can easyli achive this effect by writing your own class.

```css
.fullVH{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullVH" style="background:green">1</div>
<div class="fullVH" style="background:red">2</div>
<div class="fullVH" style="background:blue">3</div>
```

The trick here is to use viewport **height: 100vh;** instead of using **height: 100%;**
Hope this helps.

Comment: height: 100vh; - quite valuable. Thanks a lot.